# ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full with (Engine=MEMORY)

Tags: mysql, memory, heap-memory

The table size I am trying to load into the memory is 26MB. To load it into the memory I do the following:

```
SET max_heap_table_size = 1024*1024*50;
CREATE TABLE vendor_test
ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * from test_table.t_vendors ORDER BY `ID_VENDOR`;
```

The output is: `ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'vendor_test' is full`.
I have tried increasing the `max_heap_table_size` parameter up to 300MB prior to the CREATE statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `SELECT @@max_heap_table_size;` to confirm `SET max_heap_table_size = 1024*1024*50;` is working.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried that already, it does.

Comment: Note that the MEMORY storage engine does not store long varchar efficiently. If you have varchar columns in `t_vendors` that are defined with a large maximum length, but smaller data, it could be 26MB but those strings must pad out to a greater size in MEMORY engine.

Comment: @BillKarwin In my case the biggest varchar column holds 256 characters, so I guess it is not the case.

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: @BillKarwin 40287 rows.

Comment: Okay, so *each row* will occupy 255 characters in the MEMORY engine, even if the string in your original table is shorter. Suppose the string values in your varchar(255) column are really only 10 characters on average, the MEMORY table holding the same rows will be 25 times as large. If you have multiple varchar(255) columns, this gets even worse. If you use utf8 or utf8mb4, multiply by 3 or 4.

Comment: Why are you copying the data to MEMORY engine anyway? Normally InnoDB data is buffered in memory as you use it, and you can get very good performance by defining indexes to help your queries.